# Java Stream API: Разница между reduction и mutable reduction

Tags: java, java-stream

Объясните пожалуйста разницу между reduction и mutable reduction.
В документации Oracle описано, метод класса Stream reduce() это reduction, метод collect() -это mutable reduction.

```
int sum = numbers.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum)
```

Здесь понятно, что из множества значений получают одно - сумму. Т.е "сократили".

Не понятно, в чём заключается reduction в случае с collect(). Я воспринимаю  метод collect() просто как способ конвертации потока в коллекцию. Г.Шилдт в русской редации Полного руководства Java8 даёт определение потока "как последовательность объектов.В самом потоке данные не хранятся, а только перемещаются". Т.е попросту поток "разложили по полочкам" внутри коллекции. 
Было 5 эл-ов в потоке, стало 5 эл-ов в колекции. Образно говоря: Есть источник данных - файл, исходная коллекция, массив. Это бочка с водой. Присоединён шланг - это поток. Из шланга вода разливается по бутылкам - коллекция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обе эти терминальные операции `reduce()` и `collect()` преобразуют значения в стриме в результирующий объект, только в случае случае с `reduce()` обычно получается иммутабельный объект, а в случае с `collect()` - потенциально мутабельный

——

Достаточно неплохо об этом написано в [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Comment: Спасибо, @Stranger in the Q!  Перечитаю ещё раз.  Но почему-то от Вашего объяснения сразу стало понятно.

Comment: @harp1814 `ctrl+f` `Mutable reduction`